# Need advice on ATmega32u4 routing VCC

Tags: pcb-design, atmega

I have attached my current state of VCC routing of ATmega32u4.
I think I am seeking for some general advice on how to tie the VCC pins together.
Is this an acceptable way to route the pins? Sorry for such a vague question.
Routing was done with little background. I am sure there is room for improvement.

[image][image]

Comment: Could you post a wider picture including the decoupling capacitors too?

Comment: @NickAlexeev done! It may be a little hard to see. Let me know!

Comment: In general you want to avoid acute angles on traces/pads as it increases the risk of damage during manufacturing and regular use. For example, where you connect pin 2 to pin 7, I would not recommend connecting it that way. I would recommend using more of a "Y" shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a VCC Polygon Pour; The Routing is amateurish to my opinion. 
Polygon Pour will have much more current capacity (though you don't need it).

*If it is a 4-layer board, make sure you have an Internal Ground layer and tie all the grounds through a via.*

Comment: Read this for detailed design rules. It's a great resource from TI :  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza009/szza009.pdf